# Не работает пагинация WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

использую WP_Query для страницы поиска объектов недвижимости, проблема в пагинации, всегда отображается количество страниц которе есть вообще для этого типа записи. Если например открыть каталог недвижимости, там будет 10 страниц как должно быть, но на странице поиска будить отображаться также 10 страниц, даже если ничего не найдено. В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

[image: Скрин страницы поиска]

Comment: Только по картинке будет сложно сказать, что у вас может быть не так)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, нужны дополнительные параметры для the_posts_pagination(), если записи выводятся отдельным запросом с помощью new WP_Query.

https://wp-kama.ru/function/paginate_links

В примере #2 все указано